# Ansible external source of variable files - how to handle

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I'm migrating my playbooks from Jenkins to Ansible Tower.

I have two git repos:

- `main-automation`: it contains the playbooks/roles with the business logic
- `runtime-attributes`: Operations take care of hundreds of yaml dictonaries with software configurations. They are splitted in many files. They change quite often and last version should be used at runtime by the playbooks for configuring the nodes. This repo can be considered as an extended inventory.

Currently

- before running the playbooks in `main-automation`, Jenkins clones `runtime-attributes`
  in `<playbook_dir>/files/runtime-attributes`
- `main-automation` playbook loads the dictionaries using `include_vars`

What is the best approach when we migrate to Ansible Tower or using Ansible in general?
Riccardo

Comment: I'm afraid your question may lead to opinion-based answers, so I would recommend to narrow it down to the specific problem. Generally the approach is fine except the `runtime-attributes` cannot be considered an inventory unless it contains inventory files. Otherwise it's just a source of variables and their [precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) will depend on how do you load them (and in any case it's higher than the inventory variables have).

Comment: Also, side note: I've seen people migrating back from Tower to plain Ansible. It may give too much flexibility and kind of promotes manual UI interactions that may actually be unwanted when you're following configuration as code and GitOps principles.

Comment: AAP is the platform chosen by the company.
May I consider it like an Ansible collection in a GIT repo?

Comment: Renamed the title, thanks

Comment: My comment was not about the title but about the question itself. Currently, the only proper way to answer it is to refer the documentation links, which, I believe, is not what you would expect on SO.